# Joining multiple SUM() across multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables, one with forecast production weights and one with actual production weight.

A customer can and will have multiple types and multiple seasons, and will also invoice those types over the year

```
Table Estimates
Customer    Type        Weight     Season
John        A           10         2018
John        A           20         2018
John        B           10         2018
Bill        A           10         2018
Bill        C           10         2017
Robert      B           30         2017
Robert      C           10         2018


Table Actual
Customer   Type         Weight         InvoiceDate

John       A            5              2018-10-30
John       A            5              2018-10-30
John       A            5              2018-10-30
John       C            10             2018-10-30
Bill       A            5              2018-11-1
Bill       C            10             2017-11-30
Bill       C            10             2017-11-30
Bill       C            10             2017-11-30
Robert     B            30             2017-11-10
Robert     C            10             2019-2-20
```

Desired Query Would be as follows

```
select customer,
       type,
       sum(weight),
       sum(weight)
from 
       estimates,
       actual
where 
       season = 2018 and
       InvoiceDate between 2018-7-1 and 2019-6-30 and
       estimates.type = actual.type and
       estimates.customer = actual.customer
group by 
       customer,
       type
```

This give wildly large numbers

Desired result would be selecting for 2018

```
Customer   Type      Sum(Estimate)       Sum(Actual)
John       A         30                  15
John       B         10                   0
John       C          0                  10
Bill       A         10                   5
Robert     C         10                  10
```

I have tried several join and union queries attempting to solve this issue
I cant quite get my head around which join to use to get the desired result

Answer (score 0):

You can try below way -

```
select A.customer,A.type, estimated,actual
from
(
select customer,
       type,sum(wieght) as estimated
from estimate where season=2018 group by customer,type
)A inner join
(
select customer,
       type,sum(wieght) as actual
from actual where InvoiceDate between '2018-7-1' and '2019-6-30' group by customer,type
)B on A.customer=B.customer and A.type=B.type
```

Comment: Thank you looks awesome so far but still testing